# STDOUT to a TextView Box within an Activity

Tags: java, android

Hell0, I'm trying to output the shell commands to a textView box I'm getting a return missing error I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to build an Android app that runs pretty much adb commands and outputs the results of those commands to a textview box.

Java:

```
 public String runAsRoot() {

    try {
        // Executes the command.
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm list packages");

        // Reads stdout.
        // NOTE: You can write to stdin of the command using
        //       process.getOutputStream().
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();

        // Waits for the command to finish.
        process.waitFor();

        //I know im supposed to return output.toString();
        //but im trying to figure out how to return it to the textView.

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(output.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="431dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
```

Comment: `runAsRoot()` should be returning a string but it returns nothing

Comment: im sure its return output.toString(); but that outputs the data directly out to the activity window im trying to constrain it to the textview box but i can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this did it for me as it is working now!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText("Output :"+"\n"+runAsRoot());
```